# ',' is expected, how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I keep getting an error in my code that says "',' expected". I don't get it, I basically almost used the same code for my kick command (the one I am having trouble with is the ban) and it worked.

This is the code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const token = '******'

const PREFIX = '-';

Client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ban':

            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);

                if (member) {
                    member.ban({ression: 'You were bad!'}.then(() =>{
                        message.reply(`${user.tag} has been banned!`)
                    })
   It says ',' expected (bracket) ->     } else {
                    message.reply("That user isn't in the guild")
                }
            } else {
                message.reply('That user isnt in the guild');
            }


            break;
    }
});
```

Where would the comma go??

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on your `member.ban` call. Also, I think you have a typo with `ression`. It should be [`reason`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban).

```
member.ban({ression: 'You were bad!'}.then(() =>{
                                     ^ parenthesis not closed here
```

Fixed version would be:

```
member.ban({reason: 'You were bad!'}).then(() => {
```